# Press key programmatically w/ Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, keypress

I was thinking if it's possible to press a key (as `a`) with Cocoa. I already searched in the web, but I don't found anything. Actually, I don't want to use AppleScript or Python to do it. Just cocoa.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question needs more clarification: within your own app or scripting / programatically pressing keys in *other* apps?

Comment: Actually, I'm developing an Mac App, and my app will be in background, so I want to press a key just like when the user taps the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but you can work with system wide events through EventTaps.

[Quartz Event services reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html)

I'm not entirely sure what the appstore allows, I do know my app with a listening event tap has been approved. There are 2 types of taps, filtering and listening => their names are both pretty straight forward. I think using a event tap you should also be able to post new events.. ( thus fake a key press.. )

Comment: Thanks, Antwan. That's what I wanted. I just used: `CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)13, true);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e);
CFRelease(e);`